# Copying a jpeg file from Microsoft Azure Blob Storage to OneDrive

Tags: azure, copy, blob, storage, onedrive

I am new to Power Automate as its known now.

Anyway I would like to know if there is a way to copy a Jpeg file from Azure Blob Storage to a subfolder in Onedrive ?

Thank you to all of you that read this post

Marco

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could implement it with Power Automate, you could refer to my flow with the below pic.

Use the blob connector get the file content, then create the file in the onedrive folder with the content.

[image]